# download header showing an error on my server

Tags: php, header

This is my 2nd page , my first page is **download button**

```
<?php
session_start();

//user not logged in, no direct access
if (!isset($_SESSION['user'])) header("location:../admin/");

include "../config.php";
if(isset($_POST['downld'])) {
header( "Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel" );
header( "Content-disposition: attachment; filename=emc_promo_".date("m-d-Y").".xls" );
$q="select * from emc_leadgen2 order by emc_time_date desc  ";
$r=mysql_query($q);
$count=mysql_num_rows($r);
if($count>0) {?> 
<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
<table cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0"  border="1" >    
<tr><td colspan="8" align="center"><b>Lead Gen Form for EMC on <?=date("m-d-Y")?></b></td></tr>  
<tr>
<td style="padding:5px;"><b>FIRST NAME</b></td>
<td style="padding:5px;"><b>LAST NAME</b></td>
<td style="padding:5px;"><b>NAME OF ORG.</b></td>
<td style="padding:5px;"><b>JOB TITLE</b></td>
<td style="padding:5px;"><b>MAIL</b></td>
<td style="padding:5px;"><b>PHONE</b></td>
<td style="padding:5px;"><b>ADDRESS</b></td>
<td style="padding:5px;"><b>STORAGE</b></td>
<td style="padding:5px;"><b>TIME & DATE</b></td>
</tr>
<?php while($row=mysql_fetch_array($r)) {?>
<tr>
<td style="padding:5px;"><?=$row['emc_fname']?></td>
<td style="padding:5px;"><?=$row['emc_lname']?></td>
<td style="padding:5px;"><?=$row['emc_organization']?></td>
<td style="padding:5px;"><?=$row['emc_job_title']?></td>
<td style="padding:5px;"><?=$row['emc_email']?></td>
<td style="padding:5px;"><?=$row['emc_phone']?></td>  
<td style="padding:5px;"><?=$row['emc_address']?></td>
<td style="padding:5px;"><?=$row['emc_storage']?></td>
<td style="padding:5px;"><?=$row['emc_time_date']?></td>
</tr>
<?php
}
}
}
?>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

When i click on the download button , its showing this error

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   /home/content/59/8131259/html/leadyourtran/offer1/config.php:6) in
>   /home/content/59/8131259/html/leadyourtran/offer1/admin/downld.php on
>   line 8

and

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   /home/content/59/8131259/html/leadyourtran/offer1/config.php:6) in
>   /home/content/59/8131259/html/leadyourtran/offer1/admin/downld.php on
>   line 9

my line 8 and 9 are both header one only.

Comment: Usually this error occurs because the header statement must appear before any output is sent to the user. This page already addresses this topic : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/headers-already-sent-by-php/8028987#8028987

Comment: but what i am doing in my code ??

Comment: It could be that your config.php file has an echo statement. Check that file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`header()`, like `session_start()` must be called before any output or html code. If you have an output in the file included before `header()` (or a warning error), results these errors.

Check in your config.php, line 6 (specified in error mesage).

Answer (score 0):

Trying adding,

```
ob_start();
```

at the top of your php file.

If by default your `output_buffering` is `Off` and you have been unfortunate enough to send a single byte of data back to the client then your `HTTP` headers have already been sent. Which effectively prevents `session_start()` from passing the cookie header back to the client. By calling `ob_start()` you enable buffering and therefore delay sending http headers.

Borrowed from another answer,

In the "*normal case*", I don't think `ob_start` has to be called before `session_start` -- nor the other way arround.

Quoting the [manual page of `session_start`](http://www.php.net/session_start), though :

> session_start() will register internal
>   output handler for URL rewriting when
>   trans-sid is enabled. If a user uses
>   ob_gzhandler or like with ob_start(),
>   the order of output handler is
>   important for proper output. For
>   example, user must register
>   ob_gzhandler before session start.

But this is some kind of a special case : the thing is, here, that the order of output handlers is important : if you want one handler to modify things the other did, they have to be executed in the "right" order.

Generally, if you don't use that kind of handlers *(Apache and [`mod_deflate`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/mod_deflate.html) do a great job when it comes to compressing output, for instance)*, the only thing that matters is that headers must not be sent before you call `session_start` *(because, depending on your configuration, `session_start` sends cookies, which are passed as HTTP headers)*.

And headers are sent as soon as any piece of data has to be sent -- ie, as soon as there is any output, even one whitespace outside of `<?php ?>` tags :

> Note: If you are using cookie-based
>   sessions, you must call
>   session_start() before anything is
>   outputted to the browser.

`ob_start` indicates that PHP has to buffer data :

> This function will turn output
>   buffering on. While output buffering
>   is active no output is sent from the
>   script (other than headers), instead
>   the output is stored in an internal
>   buffer.

This way, output is not sent before you actually say, yourself, "*send the data*". This means headers are not send immediatly -- which means `session_start` can be called later, even if there should have been output, if `ob_start` had not been used.

*Hope this makes things a bit more clear...*